# Control draw order for geojson extrusions in MapboxGL

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

I have a set of GeoJSON polygons which I have extruded at varying heights and placed on a map to be rendered with MapboxGL.

The resulting render will seemingly place, at random, buildings in the foreground behind those in the background. What is the strategy for resolving this?[image]

Image above included for reference.

Comment: Are you rendering each building in a separate style layer?

Comment: Yeah at first I thought this was caused by the fact that I had feature layers with multiple polygons, so I broke all GeoJSONs up into independent polygons and put them in a list, which I iterated through to add to the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you render each building in a separate style layer, the buildings will be rendered in the order that the style layers are added. I encourage you to either sort the style layers by z-index or render all the buildings in the same layer.

Comment: Thanks - perhaps I am missing an obvious FAQ but I am unable to find a walkthrough on how to load a GeoJSON with different heights in a single style layer. 

It seems that the properties (e.g. height) is set at the layer level is it not? If so, then how would I indicate varying heights for different components of the multipolygon?

Comment: Just realized that was resolved by making it a feature collection and loading that in instead - thanks for your help; working now!